# Quick row search in QSqlTableModel and SQLite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qsqltablemodel

I use SQLite 3.x, Qt 5.7, C++, `QSqlTableModel`, `QTableView` classes. The table `sites` contains unique `url` column. I'd like to avoid redundant selects and minimize/exclude full resets of my model in the case of small data modifications. So, I prefer using read-only raw SQL queries and writing via `QSqlRecord` in this project. I update the row in the model through changing the corresponding `QSqlRecord` instance. But I have to make linear search of the record to update (see pseudocode below):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount(); ++i)
{
    QSqlRecord current_record = record(i);
    QString current_url = current_record.value("url").toString();
    if (current_url == url)
    {
       //updates... 
       break;
    }
}
```

I'd like to use SQLite internal means for quicker search. How can I find correct identifier (let's name it `found_id`) in SQLite in order to call `QSqlRecord record = row(found_id);`? Note that inserts and removals will be used too.

Here is simplified DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE sites (
id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
url                VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL
                         );
```

Comment: There are many variants, For example, using mapping variable like `QHash<QString, QSqlRecord> mapUrlToRecord`. After initialize it, we can quickly access to record from its url by `mapUrlToRecord.value(url)`. On updates we changing this variable too. If we want access to records from id, we just use integer as a key: `QHash<int, QSqlRecord> mapIdToRecord`

Comment: Anyway, I think that subclassing from `QAbstractTableModel` with overriding `rowCount`, `columnCount`, `data`, `setData` methods is more "true-way".